# 2D Shape Coordinates with Modern Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-4

I'm trying to render a series of 2D shapes (Rectangle, Circle) etc in modern opengl, hopefully without the use of any transformation matrices. I would like for me to be able to specify the coordinates for say a rectangle of 2 triangles like so:

```
float V[] = { 20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 
              40.0, 20.0, 0.0,
              40.0, 40.0, 0.0, 
              40.0, 40.0, 0.0,
              20.0, 40.0, 0.0,
              20.0, 20.0, 0.0 }
```

You can see that the vertex coordinates are specified in viewport? space (I believe thats what its called). Now, when this get rendered by opengl, it doesnt work because clip space goes from -1.0 to 1.0 with the origin in the center.

What would be the correct way for me to handle this? I initially thought adjusting glClipControl to upper left and 0 to 1 would work, but it didnt. With clip control set to upper left and 0 to 1, the origin was still at the center, but it did allow for the Y-Axis to increase as it moved downward (which is a start).

Ideally, I would love to get opengl to have 0.0,0.0 to be the top left and 1.0, 1.0 to be the bottom right, then I just normalise each vertex position, but I have no idea how to get opengl to use that type of coordinate system.

Comment: I think you want an orthogonal perspective.

Comment: So theres no way to beat OpenGL into doing things my way?

Comment: Well, why do you want to avoid matrices?

Comment: Simplicity really, but, if theres no other way, I'd be willing to accept a solution that takes a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can easily do these transformation without matrices in the vertex shader:

```
// From pixels to 0-1 
vPos.xy /= vResolution.xy;

// Flip Y so that 0 is top 
vPos.y = (1.-vPos.y);

// Map to NDC -1,+1
vPos.xy = vPos.xy*2.-1.;
```

Comment: That did it, Thanks!